# Connector/c++ with SSL?

Tags: ssl, mysql-connector, visual-c++-2008

How to connect to MySql using Connector/c++ over SSL?

I read about mysql_ssl_set(): seems to work only with Connector/c.

I have openSSL enabled and working for require SSL users on MySql. And I can connect remotely to MySql using Connector/c++, but cannot see how to modify parameters of sql::Connection to reference certs for SSL.

Excellent tutorial from Giri Mandalika at MySql DevZone and docs on Connector/c++ don't mention SSL, which surprised me because SSL is well documented for Connector/c...or did I miss something obvious?

I realize sql::Driver::Connect() is overloaded, with the less-commonly discussed method taking one parameter sql::ConnectOptionsMap &options. Following that trail, I found just one discussion on point: Ulf Wendel/Thomas Pollak question-and-solution here (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,367519,369534#msg-369534).

Did not work for me: when I incorporated it and tried to build (VC2008, WIN7) the build had warnings and failed.

I traced the exact causes as:
sql::ConnectPropertyVal generates locally defined symbol warning; and
std::map causes fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

With so many users out there of Connector/c++, I hoped others in the community might also be interested in how to use SSL with Connector/c++. Appreciate any ideas or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke to Giri Mandalika (on the original development team), who mentioned that SSL support was originally planned but not completed for Connector/c++.

In case others who want SSL find this question, I worked around the problem only by using Connector/c, the underlying C api which Connector/C++ was designed to wrap.

As more than six months have elapsed without any community member coming up with a specific solution to use SSL with Connector/c++ (other than the overload solution referenced in my question), I guess I have to conclude that it just isn't possible, and mark my own question as "Answered" by me.