# C++ Secure SQL Connection

Tags: c++, mysql, security

I've been searching around for this, and the answer is usually things like encrypting your password and such.

What I'm interested in is establishing a secure connection with a MySQL server (let's say that doesn't involve anything else, like installing something extra on the server), so if there was an attacker in the users network, they wouldn't be able to see the traffic because it's encrypted and secure.

How would I go about this? Would I need to look into some libraries to use along with the SQL Connection? If so how exactly (reading resources is of course accepted)?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html seems to have many details about using TLS and mysql

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql can encrypt the connections via tls. All you need to do is [configure mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html) to use the secure connection (this may involve installing additional components on the server), create the certificates, create users that authenticate using certificates.

On the client side you may have to work with connector/c because connector/c++ [may have issues with ssl connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474748/connector-c-with-ssl).

Comment: @mikk it normally does include installing something else on the server. This is your first approach. Thx for sharing Shadow.